# best way to check xml reference?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I have many references in my xml files like this:

```
<name id="key1"></name> 
<ref to="key1"></ref>
```

so what's the best way to check the ref/@to is defined in a name/@id.

XSD? DTD? or programming using XPATH?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the ways to solve this problem using XML Schema, XPath and XSLT. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In XML Schema**: [**`ID`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#ID), [**`IDREF`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#IDREF), [**`IDREFS`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#IDREFS), [`xs:key`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-key)  -- see [**this**](http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/chapter17.html) for examples.

**In XPath**: the [**`id()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-id) function.

**In XSLT**: the [**`<xsl:key>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key) declaration and the [**`key()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-key) function.

Answer (score 0):

Xml schema's ID and IDREF. [Look here](http://www.xfront.com/GlobalVersusLocal.html) for more details. You can enforce these rules using the xml schema if you have the option of defining the schema for the xml files. Otherwise XSLT/XPath.